# Are there disadvantages of using channel.Get() over channel.Consume()?

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using [streadway's amqp](https://github.com/streadway/amqp) library to connect with a rabbitmq server. 
The library provides a channel.Consume() function which returns a "**<- chan Delivery**".
It also provides a channel.Get() function which returns a "**Delivery**" among other things.

I've to implement a **pop()** functionality, and I'm using **channel.Get()**. However, the [documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Get) says:

```
"In almost all cases, using Channel.Consume will be preferred."
```

Does the *preferred* here means *recommended*? Are there any disadvantages of using channel.Get() over channel.Consume()? If yes, how do I use channel.Consume() to implement a Pop() function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the docs, yes, "preferred" does mean "recommended".

It seems that `channel.Get()` doesn't provide as many features as `channel.Consume()`, as well as being more readily usable in concurrent code due to it's returning a `chan` of `Delivery`, as opposed to each individual `Delivery` separately.

The extra features mentioned are `exclusive`, `noLocal` and `noWait`, as well as an optional [`Table`](http://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Table) of args "that have specific semantics for the queue or server."

To implement a `Pop()` function using `channel.Consume()` you could, to link to some code fragments from the [amqp example consumer](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/examples/simple-consumer/consumer.go), create a [channel using the `Consume()` function](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/examples/simple-consumer/consumer.go#L119-L127), create a [function to handle the `chan` of `Delivery`](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/examples/simple-consumer/consumer.go#L153-L164) which will actually implement your `Pop()` functionality, then [fire off the `handle()` func in a `goroutine`](https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/examples/simple-consumer/consumer.go#L132).

The key to this is that the channel (in the linked example) will block on sending if nothing is receiving. In the example, the `handle()` func uses `range` to process the entire channel until it's empty. Your `Pop()` functionality may be better served by a function that just receives the last value from the `chan` and returns it. Every time it's run it will return the latest `Delivery`.

EDIT: Example function to receive the latest value from the channel and do stuff with it (This may not work for your use case, it may be more useful if the function sent the `Delivery` on another `chan` to another function to be processed. Also, I haven't tested the code below, it may be full of errors)

```
func handle(deliveries <-chan amqp.Delivery, done chan error) {
    select {
    case d = <-deliveries:
        // Do stuff with the delivery
        // Send any errors down the done chan. for example:
        // done <- err
    default:
        done <- nil
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! however, your last line is the exact problem I'm facing. I tried to make a Pop() by using range over the Delivery channel, but returning as soon as a value is found. Of-course that returned the most recent value but also popped out all the other values from the queue in background, and so I moved to channel.Get(). I'm new to channels and goroutines. How can I implement this function to receive the latest value from the chan?

Comment: does Rabbitmq .get works in round-robin manner in case we have multiple consumers or does it atleast guarantee that message is received by only one consumer

Answer (score 6):

It really depend of what are you trying to do. If you want to get only one message from queue (first one) you probably should use `basic.get`, if you are planning to process all incoming messages from queue - `basic.consume` is what you want.

Probably, it is not platform or library specific question but rather protocol understanding question.

**UPD**

I'm not familiar with it go language well, so I will try to give you some brief on AMQP details and describe use cases.

You may get in troubles and have an overhead with `basic.consume` sometimes:

**With `basic.consume` you have such workflow:**

1. Send `basic.consume` method to notify broker that you want to receive messages

   - while this is a synchronous method, wait for `basic.consume-ok` message from broker
2. Start listening to `basic.deliver` message from server

   - this is an asynchronous method and you should take care by yourself situations where no messages on server available, e.g. limit reading time

**With `basic.get` you have such workflow:**

1. send synchronous method `basic.get` to broker

   - wait for `basic.get-ok` method, which hold message(s) or `basic.empty` method, which denote situation no message available on server

*Note about synchronous and asynchronous methods:* synchronous is expected to have some response, whether asynchronous doesn't

*Note on `basic.qos` method `prefetch-count` property:* it is ignored when `no-ack` property is set on `basic.consume` or `basic.get`.

Spec has a note on `basic.get`: "this method provides a direct access to the messages in a queue using a synchronous dialogue that is designed for specific types of application where synchronous functionality is more important than performance" which applies for continuous messages consumption.

My personal tests show that getting in row 1000 messages with `basic.get` (0.38659715652466) is faster than getting 1000 messages with `basic.consume` one by one (0.47398710250854) on RabbitMQ 3.0.1, Erlang R14B04 in average more than 15%.

If consume only one message in main thread is your case - probably you have to use `basic.get`.

You still can consume only one message asynchronously, for example in separate thread or use some event mechanism. It would be better solution for you machine resource sometimes, but you have to take care about situation where no message available in queue.

If you have to process message one by one it is obvious that `basic.consume` should be used, I think

Comment: What I'm trying to do is exactly what basic.Get() does, but my question was whether the "preferred" in docs mean "recommended", i.e., even if I'm well off using Get(), do the docs still recommend that I should use Consume() and not Get() (as there might be some disadvantages in the way Get itself is implemented etc.)?